# Finding the form of T with $T(s_1s_2)=T(s_1)T(s_2)$

Tags: group-theory, renormalization

I'm studying renormalization group theory from "Quantum and Statistical Field Theory by M. Le Bellac". At page 78 he is linearizing the renormalization group transformation around a fixed point. The transformation is $K_\alpha=K^*_\alpha+\delta K_\alpha \approx \sum_\beta T_{\alpha\beta}(s) \delta K_\beta$ with $T_{\alpha\beta}(s) = \frac{\partial K_\alpha}{\partial K'_\beta}$ He states that by using $T(s_1s_2)=T(s_1)T(s_2)$ with $s_1=1+\delta$ and $s_2=s$ with delta infinitesimal it can be proven:
$$T(s) = exp\left(\frac{dT}{d\ln s}\rvert_{s=1} \ln s \right)$$ and I'm failing in proving this last equation. I've tried using Taylor on $T(s_1s_2)=T(s+\delta s)=T(s)+\frac{dT}{d(s)}s=T(s)T(1+\delta)$ but I'm not clear on how to make progress after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the one hand
$$ T(s_1 s_2) = T(s+\delta s) = T(s) + \delta s \frac{dT}{ds'}\bigg|_{s=s'} + O(\delta^2)$$
while on the other hand
$$ T(s_1 s_2) = T(s) T(1+\delta) = T(s) \left[ 1+\delta \frac{dT}{ds}\bigg|_{s=1}+O(\delta^2)\right]$$
where we used $T(1)=1$. Comparing we get the equation
$$ s \frac{dT}{ds} = T \frac{dT}{ds}\bigg|_{s=1}$$
which can be solved by direct integration, when noting that $dT/ds|_{s=1}$ is a constant (independent of $s$).

$$ \frac{dT}{ds}\bigg|_{s=1} \frac{ds}{s} = \frac{dT}{T} \rightarrow
 \ln T = \frac{dT}{ds}\bigg|_{s=1} \ln s + C$$
and the boundary condition $T(1)=1$ fixes $C=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much